# Topological Four-Manifolds that are not Simply Connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I am familiar with the result of Freedman that closed, simply connected four manifolds may be characterized up to homeomorphism by their intersection forms. This result is basically an extension of $h$-cobordism to dimension $4$ in the topological category.

I am wondering though if we remove the simply connected assumption, for what fundamental groups is there a known classification and in terms of what entities is the classification given?

Anecdotally I have heard that Freedman's classification can be generalized to other fundamental groups but cannot seem to find any documentation to support this.

Comment: This work was extended (by Freedman himself) to "small" fundamental groups, say, virtually nilpotent.